# How to move files from GitHub to web server

Tags: git, github

I am developing an application where client is using GitHub for source control (I am new to GitHub). I was asked to create an account on Git and then I was added to a repository. I cloned repository on my local machine, Did some work and now Commited and pushed files on GitHub using `SourceTree`. I logged in to that Git account and it is showing my last commits.

Now my client has asked me to upload files from Git to server. I haven't done it before, I searched but couldn't be able to find the solution.

So kindly guide me how can I upload my commits files to server from Github?

Comment: There are lots of different ways you can do this depending on how your client's server is set up. There are tools like capistrano, with heroku you just push to a different git remote, or you ssh into the server and clone as John Zwinck indicated. You're going to have to ask your client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple way is just to `git clone` from GitHub on the server itself.  Then when you want to update, it's just `git pull`.  If you can't do that, you can just `rsync` the files to the server from your development copy.

Comment: Into your computer.  If this doesn't make sense I'm afraid you'll need to get some local, one-on-one help.